# Pass own params in Rest Layout Service using Custom Data Fetcher

Tags: jss, sitecore-api, layout-service

I was wondering if there's anyway to override the payload in the Rest Layout Service using my own custom params. I'm upgrading the Frontend JSS, so I need to make sure the there's no other API Changes / Sitecore Changes needed.

This is what I currently have when I try to do an Http Request in the Rest Layout Service

```
<BASE_URL>forms/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=<SITECORE_PATH>&sc_apikey=<API_KEY>&sc_site=<SITE>&sc_lang=<LANGUAGE>&tracking=<TRACKING>
```

and I want this to be over written into:

```
<BASE_URL>forms/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=<SITECORE_PATH>&subscription-key=<SUBSCRIPTION-KEY>&sc_lang=<LANGUAGE>&tracking=<TRACKING>
```

I'm trying to follow this [guide](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/19/sitecore-headless-development/fetch-layout-data-using-a-custom-rest-data-fetcher.html) from the sitecore docs, but it doesn't seem to add the key that I want to be added.

Code:

RouteHandler:

```
      const key = {};
      let fetchOptions = {};

      ....
    
      if (process.env.SUBS_KEY) {
        key['subscription-key'] = process.env.SUBS_KEY;
      }

      fetchOptions = {
        ...key,
        sc_lang: 'en',
      };

      const apiUrl = config.sitecoreApiHost;

      layoutServiceInstance
        .fetchLayoutData(sitecoreRoutePath, language, apiUrl, fetchOptions)
        .then((routeData) => {
          if (routeData!== null && routeData.sitecore.route) {
            // Update the JSS store instance with the fetched data.
            // This will signal the RouteHandler to update/re-render, as well as any components
            // that are referencing the JSS store instance in their `data` object.
            this.$jss.store.setSitecoreData(routeData);
            this.notFound = false;
          } else {
            // this.$jss.store.setSitecoreData(routeData);
            this.notFound = true;
          }
          this.loading = false;
        });
```

Layout Service Factory:

```
import config from '../temp/config';
import axios from 'axios';
import { RestLayoutService } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-vue';
import {
  AxiosDataFetcher,
} from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss';
function dataFetcher(url, data) {
  return new AxiosDataFetcher().fetch(url, data);
}

export class LayoutServiceFactory {
  create() {
    return new RestLayoutService({
      apiHost: config.sitecoreApiHost,
      apiKey: config.sitecoreApiKey,
      siteName: config.jssAppName,
      tracking: false, // if you wish to disable tracking
      // provide your custom data fetcher to the service instance
      dataFetcherResolver: () => dataFetcher,
    });
  }
}

export const layoutServiceFactory = new LayoutServiceFactory();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a configuration object to the `AxiosDataFetcher` instance and modify your request.

Based on the [AxiosDataFetcher source code](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/release/21.0.0/packages/sitecore-jss/src/axios-fetcher.ts), you can pass options to the `AxiosDataFetcher` instance.

When providing options for the `AxiosDataFetcher`, you essentially configure Axios request and/or response [interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors).

To modify your request before sending it, you can use [Axios request config options](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config).

So the code might change as follows (**untested**):

```
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { 
  AxiosDataFetcher,
  RestLayoutService,
  LayoutServiceData
} from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss';
import config from './config';
// define your custom data fetcher
function dataFetcher(url: string, data?: unknown): Promise<AxiosResponse<LayoutServiceData>> {
  return new AxiosDataFetcher({
    onReq: () => {
      // Do something before request is sent and/or modify the default config
      const myCustomURl = config.url + "&key=value"
      const config = {
        // customize request method, headers, cookies, etc. See Axios request options.
        url: myCustomUrl
      }
      // return the new configuration for Axios request interceptors
      return config
    }, 
    onReqError: () => {
      // request error handling
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }, 
    onRes:() => {
      // Any 2xx status code triggers this 
      // Do something with response data then return the modified response
      return response;
    }, 
    onResError:() => {
      // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
      // Do something with response error
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }, // response error handling
    debugger?: Debugger; // here you can configure a custom [JSS debugger](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/7dd7fa91f4133348169fed390c5bee1b1ddabd07/packages/sitecore-jss/src/debug.ts)
  }).fetch(url, data);
}

export const layoutService = new RestLayoutService({
  apiHost: config.sitecoreApiHost,
  apiKey: config.sitecoreApiKey,
  siteName: config.jssAppName,
  tracking: false, // if you wish to disable tracking
  // provide your custom data fetcher to the service instance
  dataFetcherResolver: () => dataFetcher
});
```

I hope this gets you on the right track.